# How to style checkbox in custom tag to appear as a seat

Tags: java, css, checkbox

I am developing a project in which i'm displaying certain checkboxes to user that he may select a few of them as his/her seat as in movie hall or airplane. I want checkbox to be displayed as chairs or some other image how can i do it. The generation of checkboxes is happening in custom tag (java web project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this  then u should write a custom java script code for this purpose.
Create image and then associate the states (true / false) with them and when user perform the select(Click) operation on those image then change the state associated with Image.

Here is a link from where u can learn how to implement this
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/vwphillips/ImageCheckBox/ImageCheckBox.htm

Answer (score 2):

Please go thro the HTML from below URL. Here background images are applied to checkboxes.

http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/demo.html

You may also use the same logic, have two images. One is for before select, during onclick change the another background image.